# Como almacenar un Json en un vector donde pueda iterar en angular

Tags: json, array, angular

estoy comenzandon con Angular. tengo un servicio el cual se conecta a una API y me devuelve un Json. el json viene como un vector de objetos y lo que quiero hacer es poder devolver un vector en el que pueda iterar normalmente escribiendo vector[i].nombre desde el .html de la componente donde importo dicho servicio ya que actualmente puedo acceder al vector es haciendo vector[i][i].nombre como puedo hacerlo? hasta ahora lo que tengo es lo siguiente pero me da error.

este es el servicio:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Inmueble } from '../modelos/inmueble';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HostlistService {
  inmuebles: Inmueble[];
  vector: any[];

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'text/html',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS'
    })
  }


  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {

  }


  getInmuebles():Inmueble[]{
    this.http.get('URL',this.httpOptions).subscribe(
      result => {
        this.vector = Object.values(result)
        this.vector[1][1].nomb_prod_c;
        this.inmuebles[0].nombre = this.vector[1][1].nomb_prod_c;
        for (let i=0; i<=3; i++){
          //this.inmuebles[i].nombre=this.vector[1][i].nomb_prod_c;
          //console.log(this.inmuebles[0].nombre);
          //console.log(this.vector[1][i].nomb_prod_c);
          console.log(this.inmuebles[0]);
        }

        }
      );
      return this.inmuebles;
  }

}
```

esta es la interfaz donde defino el tipo inmueble:

```js
export interface Inmueble {
  nombre: string;
  id: string;
  estacionamiento: number;
  baño: number;
  foto1: string;
  foto2: string;
  foto3: string;
  foto4: string;
  foto5: string;
  precio: number;
}
```

aqui esta la componente donde lo llamo y en el .html de esta componente es donde quisiera mostrar los datos del vector:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HostlistService } from '../servicios/hostlist.service';
import {$,jQuery} from 'jquery';
import { Inmueble } from '../modelos/inmueble';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-slider',
  templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider.component.css']
})
export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {
  inmuebles: any[];
  i = 1;
  url: string = "d782a4ae-733f-b7c4-ed11-5ba553455e04_fot01_c";

  constructor(private hostlistService: HostlistService) { }
  ngOnInit() {

    //console.log(this.url);
    this.inmuebles=this.hostlistService.getInmuebles();
    //console.log(this.inmuebles[0].nombre);
  }

  anteriorInmueble(){
    this.i=this.i-1;
  }

  siguienteInmueble(){
    this.i=this.i+1;
  }

}
```

Y este es el error que me esta mostrando en consola:

```js
ERROR TypeError: "_this.inmuebles is undefined"
    getInmuebles hostlist.service.ts:31
    RxJS 11
    Angular 8
core.js:15724
    Angular 4
    RxJS 5
    Angular 11
```

Aqui estan unas fotos reales del archivo Json:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Fijate si podes poner el json tal cual como lo recibis. No hay llaves ni corchetes en lo que agregaste.

Comment: @Juan ya lo edite amigo. puedes verlo. es un vector de objetos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error puntual del `undefined` es porque solo declaraste el vector pero no está inicializado:

```
// declaración
inmuebles: Inmueble[];

// inicialización vacía.
inmuebles = [];

// o todo en un paso
inmuebles: Inmueble[] = [];
```

Las cabeceras de Access control están de más. Las que estás usando las tiene que mandar el server como respuesta a pedidos de autorización que envía el navegador del usuario.

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS'
```

Y lo que estás haciendo es un `GET`. El `GET` no lleva un body por lo tanto no tiene un "Content". Por lo que tampoco tiene sentido enviar la cabecera de "`Content-type`".

El Servicio idealmente no debería procesar los datos, sino que sea el componente el que los procesa. 
Si se hiciera así, el servicio devolvería el Observable al compoente.

```
getInmuebles():Inmueble[]{
    return this.http.get<any>('URL',this.httpOptions);
```

Y el componente:

`result` debe contener la estructura del json ya como objeto, por lo que podés iterar el array de inmuebles directamente.

```
inmuebles: Inmueble[] = []; // Movíendolo del servicio a al componente
this.hostlistService.getInmuebles().subscribe(
    result => {
        if(result.success === true){
            for(const item of result.data) {
                const inmueble = new Inmueble();
                inmueble.nombre = item.nomb_prod_c;
                // resto de asignaciones.
                inmuebles.push(inmueble);
            }
        }
    },
    error => {
        console.log(error);
    }
);
```

**1ra EDICIÓN**

> ERROR in src/app/modelos/inmueble.ts(2,18): error TS1246: An interface
>   property cannot have an initializer.
>   src/app/modelos/inmueble.ts(3,14): error TS1246

En lugar de `interface` usar un `class` para poder instanciar objetos con estos atributos.

```
export class Inmueble {
  nombre: string;
  id: string;
  estacionamiento: number;
  baño: number;
  foto1: string;
  foto2: string;
  foto3: string;
  foto4: string;
  foto5: string;
  precio: number;
}
```

Comment: amigo me muestra estos errores: ERROR in src/app/modelos/inmueble.ts(2,18): error TS1246: An interface property cannot have an initializer.
src/app/modelos/inmueble.ts(3,14): error TS1246: An interface property cannot have an initializer.
src/app/slider/slider.component.ts(20,23): error TS2339: Property 'success' does not exist on type 'Object'.
src/app/slider/slider.component.ts(21,42): error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Object'.
src/app/slider/slider.component.ts(23,42): error TS2693: 'Inmueble' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Comment: De todos esos errores el que mas me preocupa es el que dice: error TS2693: 'Inmueble' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here , y en la consola del navegador me muestra: ERROR ReferenceError: "Inmueble is not defined" . De todos los errores esos son los que mas me preocupan porque detienen la ejecucion, ya que coloque un console.log antes de "const inmueble = new Inmueble();" y si se muestra, pero luego de eso se echa a perder todo. intente incializar el objeto pero no funcionó, sabras que pueda estar sucediendo?

Comment: Inmueble está declarado como interface y en mi respuesta lo usé como una clase. Las alternativas son o redefinrlo como clase (ver 1ra edición en la respuesta), o dejarlo como interface pero cambiarle los atributos al inmueble para matchear lo que viene en el json y después asignar los objetos recibidos a variables de este tipo (hay que cambiar lo que está dentro del `for - of`).

Comment: Oye amigo, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me servió de mucho. Aunque sigo teniendo problemas. si ejecuto el codigo por primera vez me muestra estos errores: ERROR in src/app/slider/slider.component.ts(21,23): error TS2339: Property 'success' does not exist on type 'Object'. alguna idea xq pasa eso? pero si lo modifico por result [0] y reuslt[1] como las posiciones de success y data respectivamente el codigo si se ejecuta, pero cuando los mando a imprimir dice "undined" y no me muestra los datos en el .html. una vez ejecutado si coloco result.success y result.data si se ejecuta.

Comment: agregue fotos reales del Json.

Comment: Fijate que agregué en el servicio el tipo de dato devuelto por get. Lo puse como `<any>`. En lugar de any, si querés ser más especíico, podés usar una interface o una clase que replique la estructura del json devuelto.

Comment: Funcionó perfecto, ya entiendo porque daba error, ya que el get estaba devolviendo un tipo de dato anonimo. Eres una gran persona, muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo en resolver mi problema y disculpa tantas preguntas, apenas estoy comenzando con Angular. Habría una forma de comunicarme contigo en un futuro fuera de esta vía? voy a calificar tu respuesta.

Comment: amigo una ultima pregunta. estoy intentando imprimir los datos del vector inmuebles y solo puedo imprimir los de la posicion 0, desde la posicion 1 en adelante me dice: "_this.inmuebles[1] is undefined" a que se deberá eso? imprimir la longitud del vector y es la correcta, es decir, si se estan insertando los inmuebles. que podrá estar pasando ahi? el vectroe inmuebles esta inicializado en su declaración asi: inmuebles: Inmueble[] = [];